# How to make nginx fail earlier when there is no route to host?

Tags: nginx

- If the `port` of my upstream's backend is closed, usually nginx fail very quickly and try the other backend, in the error log I can see

> connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

- If my upstream's backend is down and there is no route to the host, nginx fail very slowly (~3 seconds) and causing delay in term of user experience, and in the error log I can see

> connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream

So, it is possible to reduce the `3 seconds` delay when nginx found out that the backend is not available?

Comment: Did you try setting proxy_connect_timeout to lower values?

Comment: @AndreiMikhaltsov, the `proxy_connect_timeout` is irrelevant as it is default to `60s`, but from my test, during the host not found situation, the timeout is around `3s`

Comment: You might be hitting a TCP parameter, not an nginx setting.  Take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/295390/how-can-i-tune-the-initial-tcp-retransmit-timeout (tl;dr the 3 second timeout is built into the kernel)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. This is system timeout for allow routers decide that destination is unreachable for your machine.

But you can write service-prober (if your backends are known), which will probe services and if make embedded OS firewall answer instantly with ICMP host-unreachable message through iptables or ipfw.