# Initial SYN timeout on linux

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel

When establishing a TCP connection, what is the timeout for the first SYN packet sent? If no answer is received another SYN packet is resent (up to `net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries`) with approximately doubling the timeout. I'm wondering how can I check or alter the initial timeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The initial retransmission timeout setting is hardcoded in the kernel to be 1 second in modern versions: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.11/source/include/net/tcp.h#L142

```
#define TCP_TIMEOUT_INIT ((unsigned)(1*HZ)) /* RFC6298 2.1 initial RTO value
```

The constant is referenced in `tcp.c`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L420

You cannot change it without recompiling the kernel: [How can I tune the initial TCP retransmit timeout?](https://serverfault.com/questions/295390/how-can-i-tune-the-initial-tcp-retransmit-timeout) (it seems that it used to be 3 seconds in older versions)